# Does this PDE have a specific name?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, linear-pde

Does this PDE have a specific name?

$$x \frac{\partial u }{\partial t}= A \frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial
 x^2}$$

In the absence of $x$, it is known as heat equation.

thanks in advance for answers

Comment: I think it is a variant of the [heat equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/TheHeatEquation.aspx) where the specific heat or mass density isn't constant.

Comment: @Axion004 yes it could be, if we take c(x)= x. But I think it deserves a specific name